# How to disable primeng p-table selectionmode?

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using angular primeng `<p-table>` (a shared component) and have my `[selectionMode]` as `multiselect`.
Right now i am only able to check the checkbox by clicking on the row only i want to be able to check the checkbox by clicking on the checkbox itself.

Is there a way to disable `multiselect` `selectionmode` for my `data-table` so that I can check the checkbox by clicking on the box itself and not the row? I cannot delete the `selectionmode` from the p-table since it is being used at multiple places.

**This is my p-table which is a shared component.**

```
<p-table #table 
         [value]="data" 
         [columns]="columns" 
         [scrollable]="true" 
         scrollHeight="420px" 
         [(selection)]="selections"
         [selectionMode]="multiselect ? 'multiple' : 'single'" 
         (onRowSelect)="onSelect($event)"
         (onRowUnselect)="onUnselect($event)" 
         [sortField]="sortField" 
         (onSort)="onSort($event)" 
         [paginator]="paged"
         [rows]="pageSize" 
         [rowsPerPageOptions]="ROWCOUNT_OPTIONS" 
         [currentPageReportTemplate]="PAGE_REPORT"
         [showCurrentPageReport]="showCurrentPageReport" 
         (onLazyLoad)="onLazyLoad($event)" 
         (onPage)="onPageChange($event)"
         [lazy]="lazy"
         [lazyLoadOnInit]="lazyLoadOnInit" 
         [loading]="loading" 
         [totalRecords]="totalRecords"
         paginatorDropdownAppendTo="body" 
         compareSelectionBy="equals" 
         [class]="isEmpty ? 'h-scrollable' : ''"
         [resizableColumns]="true" 
         columnResizeMode="expand">
```

**This is my html for the usage:**

```
<data-table #productTable 
            [columns]="columns"
            [data]="data" 
            [loading]="loading" 
            [multiselect]="true" 
            selectionmode = ""
            defaultSortField="necLec">
</data-table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. i just changed the selectionmode to none from multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `selectionMode=''` worked for me. Not `'none'`.