# How to remove table selectionMode completely based on a condition?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

`p-table` allows us to add `selectionMode` property when we want to enable row selection. This can take '**single**' or '**multiple**' as possible values. What I want is to disable row selection completely if a variable `_selectionMode` is **NONE**

The only way I can think is by adding the `p-table` component conditionally like this:

```
<p-table *ngIf="_selectedMode !== 'NONE'"
    [value]="products"
    selectionMode="single"
    [(selection)]="selectedProduct1"
    dataKey="code"
  >
<p-table *ngIf="_selectedMode === 'NONE'"
    [value]="products"
    [(selection)]="selectedProduct1"
    dataKey="code"
```

> 

but if I do this, I have to duplicate all the attribute bindings on `p-table` (and there are quite a lot of them in my project). Is there a better way of disabling row selection conditionally?

Simple stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo-ygnjsx)

Answer (score 1):

set `selectionMode` to `none` for no selection.

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63077675/how-to-disable-primeng-p-table-selectionmode) do upvote!

```
<p-toast></p-toast>
<button (click)="selectionMode = 'single'">single</button>
<button (click)="selectionMode = 'none'">none</button>
<button (click)="selectionMode = 'multiple'">multiple</button>
<div class="card">
  <h5>Single</h5>
  <p>
    In single mode, a row is selected on click event of a row. If the row is
    already selected then the row gets unselected.
  </p>
  <p-table
    [value]="products"
    [selectionMode]="selectionMode"
    [(selection)]="selectedProduct1"
    dataKey="code"
  >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
      <tr [pSelectableRow]="product">
        <td>{{ product.code }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.category }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo-ezbyyg)

Comment: 'none' is not an official value for selectionMode as per PrimeNG's documentation. You can put in 'abcd' also and it would behave the same way as 'none'. More importantly, putting 'none' leaves highlighting on row hover and also changes the pointer. Removing the selectionMode behaves differently than setting its vaue to 'none'

Comment: @Daud you're going to have to consider it as a way of turning of selection, the rest of your requirements can be done with css

Comment: Setting it to null instead of 'none' solves the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo-yaj3fb?file=package.json

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by setting the `selectionMode` property to **null** (via property binding) as shown [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tableselection-demo-yaj3fb?file=package.json). Additionally, you need to set `pSelectableRowDisabled` to **true** for each row